# I can't change my codes that under the build folder

Tags: android, kotlin, figma

I just imported UI package that created from Figma using Relay plug-in. When I've finished the design I've added some parameters from plug-in to some vectors those are some "onTap" parameter.

But when it's imported to Android Studio, I saw that I couldn't change the codes of "LoginPage.kt" for this error: "Files under the "build" folder are generated and should not be edited."

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the code of any file you need to go the `src` folder and from there you can navigate to right file. Files under `build` folder are auto generated files which are generated while you build your application and thus cannot be changed.